# Initialize Graphics Directives

Tags: graphics

Is it possible to initialize `Graphics` Directives when constructing `Graphics`?
(=when writing a code for a `Graphics`?)

To make you understand here is an imaginary code :

```
Graphics[{Opacity[0.5], Red, Disk[], Green, Disk[{1, 0}, 1],
  Directive["Initialize"], Blue, Disk[{2, 0}, 1]}]
```

`Directive["Initialize"]` is an imaginary code. I hope it act like `Opacity[1.]`

I upload a screenshot and codes :

[image]

```
Graphics[{Opacity[0.5], Red, Disk[], Green, Disk[{1, 0}, 1],
  Blue, Disk[{2, 0}, 1]}]

Show[Graphics[{Opacity[0.5], Red, Disk[], Green, Disk[{1, 0}, 1]}],
 Graphics[{Blue, Disk[{2, 0}, 1]}]]

Graphics[{Opacity[0.5], Red, Disk[], Green, Disk[{1, 0}, 1],
  Directive["Initialize"], Blue, Disk[{2, 0}, 1]}]
```

Note that there is a built-in `Directive`. Find ref/Directive in the MMA document.

Comment: You can use `{...}` to apply directives only to some of the primitives: try `{{Opacity[0.5],...},Blue,...}`, which will make sure that the "effect" off `Opacity[0.5]` "stops" before `Blue`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making Lukas's suggestion in comments into a symbol with [`UpValues`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UpValues.html) that make it behave like your `Directive["Initialize"]`:

```
resetDirectives /: {a___, resetDirectives[], b___} := {{a}, b}

Graphics[{AbsolutePointSize[15], Purple, Point[{-2, 0}], Opacity[0.5],
   Red, Disk[], Green, Disk[{1, 0}, 1], Blue, AbsoluteThickness[5], 
  Disk[{2, 0}, 1], Point[{4, 0}], 
  Line[Prepend[Last@#]@# &@CirclePoints[{4, 0}, 1, 3]]}]
```

[image]

```
Graphics[{AbsolutePointSize[15], Purple, Point[{-2, 0}], Opacity[0.5],
   Red, Disk[], Green, Disk[{1, 0}, 1], 
  resetDirectives[], 
  Blue, AbsoluteThickness[5], Disk[{2, 0}, 1], 
  Point[{4, 0}], Line[Prepend[Last@#]@# &@CirclePoints[{4, 0}, 1, 3]]}]
```

[image]

```
Graphics[{AbsolutePointSize[15], Purple, Point[{-2, 0}], Opacity[0.5],
   Red, Disk[], Green, Disk[{1, 0}, 1], 
  resetDirectives[], 
  Blue, AbsoluteThickness[5], Disk[{2, 0}, 1], 
  resetDirectives[], 
  Point[{4, 0}], Line[Prepend[Last@#]@# &@CirclePoints[{4, 0}, 1, 3]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Works perfectly! and it is outstanding example of `UpValues`! Very impressive!

Comment: For users : note that the definition of resetDirectives [] has an inductive structure. Note that there is `{ }` for only `a` in `{{a}, b}`.